# transform List<XElement> to List<XElement.Value>

Tags: linq-to-xml

I have a result of a xlinq that is an enumerable with id and phones, I want to transform that to a Dictionary, that part is simple, however the part of transforming the phone numbers from a XElement to a string its proving hard

```
xLinqQuery.ToDictionary(e => e.id, e => e.phones.ToList());
```

will return `Dictionary<int, List<XElement>>` what i want is a `Dictionary<int, List<String>>`

I tried with `e.phones.ToList().ForEach(...)`
some strange SelectMany, etc ot no avail

Thanks

Comment: maybe you can clarify the types you are seeing here: "will return Dictionary> what i want is a Dictionary >"

Comment: @magnifico, the angle brackets were unquoted, so the snippets where unreadable.

Answer (score 2):

```
var dict = xLinqQuery.ToDictionary(
    e => e.id,
    e => e.phones.Select(p => p.Value).ToList());
```